# jQuery HTML changes before fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to make a simple navigation on a one page document. The content is dynamically changed via JavaScript. I am using the following code to change my content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cgpg_1(){
        $("#jquery_content").fadeOut("slow").html("hello").fadeIn();
    }
</script>
```

It works fine in terms of changing the content but what it doesn't do is fade out while it changes the content. It will always change the html of `#jquery_content` and *then* fadeout and fade back in. Which obviously makes no sense as the fade out is supposed to make the page look neater when navigating through it.

What do I need to do to fix the jQuery?

Comment: a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the callback function.

```
function cgpg_1(){
    $("#jquery_content").fadeOut("slow", function(){
         $(this).html("hello").fadeIn();
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! I'll be accepting this answer :) ps, whats the reason for this? I mean why does html() run asynchronously?

Comment: @fermionoid You are welcome. because `html` is executed before animation is complete. Callback function is executed when animation is complete.

Comment: This is because the fading out effect takes time to complete and immediate function is fired. Now if you are using callback then it guarantees that once previous event is fully done only then the inner function (callback function) will execute

Comment: `html()` doesn't run asynchronously, `fadeOut()` does.

Comment: @juhana thanks for correcting me :) I'm quite new to javascript as you can see

Comment: @undefined, by the way, you can edit your answer and put some explanation. It doesn't hurt ;)